How do i solve the following error?
Im doing an audit  and after i cloned the repo i run npm i as i was asked but i got this error
root@DESKTOP-2D4MA2J:~/2024-05-predy# npm i 
npm warn deprecated zksync-web3@0.14.4: This package has been deprecated in favor of 
zksync-ethers@5.0.0
npm error code 1
npm error path \\wsl.localhost\Ubuntu\root\2024-05-predy\node_modules\classic-level
npm error command failed
npm error command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node-gyp-build
npm error '\\wsl.localhost\Ubuntu\root\2024-05-predy\node_modules\classic-level'
npm error CMD.EXE was started with the above path as the current directory.
npm error UNC paths are not supported.  Defaulting to Windows directory.
npm error gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm error gyp info using node-gyp@10.1.0
npm error gyp info using node@20.12.1 | win32 | x64
npm error gyp info find Python using Python version 3.12.2 found at 
"C:\Python312\python.exe"
npm error gyp ERR! configure error 
npm error gyp ERR! stack Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Windows\build'
npm error gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.22631
npm error gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" 
"C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node- 
gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
npm error gyp ERR! cwd C:\Windows
npm error gyp ERR! node -v v20.12.1
npm error gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v10.1.0
npm error gyp ERR! not ok
npm error A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\npm- 
cache\_logs\2024-05-29T06_28_57_816Z-debug-0.log  


I suggest you to add further context to your question, which software are you running, wich environment? This info may be useful to solve the question.
